# >200 Reputation on Area51 doesn't grant bonus to other StackExchange sites

Tags: support, status-bydesign, area-51, association-bonus

My [Area 51 account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/35447/emansipater), which is the first StackExchange site I signed up for, has more than 200 reputation.  However, none of [the new accounts I've added since then](https://stackexchange.com/users/46f4cfe3-9250-4ca0-8256-f1d6ccc4156b?tab=accounts) have received the +100 bonus that is referred to in almost every FAQ.

I've tried un-linking and re-linking the accounts as most answers here about bonus reputation suggest, but to no avail.  I was also unable to find an existing question with my precise situation--and **definitely** not one that was tagged with both the linked-accounts and area51 tags.  The closest one I've found was [4 months old and required staff intervention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72504/why-dont-i-have-more-rep).

Does Area51 not grant that bonus to other sites intentionally, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is by design at the moment; Area 51 is important, but it's not Q&A.

Comment: Unfortunately Area 51-ers often have to go ask meta-questions on other sites as part of the process--something they don't start with the permission to do.  For example I had to ask [this question](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/questions/286/is-this-a-good-place-to-ask-and-answer-questions-about-bitcoin) in non-meta and have someone else move it.  After migration I didn't even have enough reputation to comment on it!

Comment: Given that any skills of "being helpful" which would transfer from [mechanics](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) to [rpg](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/) are currently being incentivised, might be worth it to assume the same for Area 51.

Comment: @emans I would urge you to get +200 on any network Q&A site :)

Comment: I certainly will.  But Area 51 just happens to be how I discovered Stack Exchange.  It's the _order_ of things that has slowed me down.

Comment: @eman I love Area 51 and it is absolutely central to everything we do, but *so is expert Q&A* -- that's our bedrock, and experience with Q&A is essential to understanding what goes on at Area 51 and every other http://stackexchange.com/sites